# Third mouse button as paste in Chromium

Tags: chromium

Has anyone succeeded in getting Chromium to use the third mouse button as paste? At least on the select to copy side I am aware of [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dnejpbhppnaekhejffmdallnhfgleene) but unaware of anyone who figured out how to have unix-style paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works for me - ish.

The field needs focus before you can middle-click-paste so just left click, then middle click.